# What's the currently correct way to mark publication date on a HTML page?

Tags: html

For what I *Google-searched*, looks like that the `<time>` element was dropped and bring back to HTML5 specs later (right?) *

I want to clarify:

- ***Right now*, what is the correct way to mark the publication date on an article on a HTML page?**
- **Is `pubdate` still supported?**

I'm using the following way:

```
<time datetime='2014-07-02' pubdate>July 2014</time>
```

Is it correct?

---

* [[1]](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/10/html5-drops-the-time-element/)[[2]](http://www.zeldman.com/2011/10/31/goodbye-html5-element/)[[3]](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2011/goodbye-html5-time-hello-data/)[[4]](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/11/w3c-adds-time-element-back-to-html5/)[[5]](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/02/the-html5-time-element-is-back-and-better-than-ever/)[[6]](http://readwrite.com/2011/11/04/developer_backlash_html5_element#awesm=~oIRAU1KKbK0aha)

Comment: Hi @talles, if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would embed [schema.org Article structured data](http://schema.org/Article) on the page and use the `datePublished` property.

From their homepage:

> This site provides a collection of schemas that webmasters can use to
>   markup HTML pages in ways recognized by major search providers... Search engines including Bing, Google, Yahoo! and Yandex rely
>   on this markup to improve the display of search results, making it
>   easier for people to find the right Web pages.

Here's an example, adapted from the Article example to include `datePublished` per [the spec for dates](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced), which you'll note uses the `time` element:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
  <span itemprop="name">How to Tie a Reef Knot</span>
  by <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
  published <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-07-02">July 2nd, 2014</time>
</div>
```

To answer whether `pubdate` is still supported, you can refer to the [latest HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) directly, and see that aside from global attributes, the only other attribute specified is the `datetime` attribute for indicating a machine-readable version of the content. If you scroll further, one of the examples for this element in the spec uses the schema.org vocabulary for an article's publication date.

Using a microdata format like schema.org will ultimately give you more control over how search engines and other crawlers interpret the data on your page.